# Confused about Ruby syntax

Tags: ruby

I do not know how to put this. I saw following syntax in several places, like

```
def test 
{
t: a,
h: b

}
end
```

..

```
def pieces
    [
      'the horse and the hound and the horn that belonged to',
      'the farmer sowing his corn that kept',
    ]
  end
```

I am confuse about the def syntax. I know it is function but when to use {} and when to use []. Not sure what it called so I cannot search the internet.
I have php knowledge and not familiar with this type of syntax. For the first one, in php I would write like

```
function test ($a,$b)
{
$t=$a,
$h=$b
}
```

For second one, I would create an array inside the function.

Please help. Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 4):

Braces( `{}` ) or brackets ( `[]` ) in Ruby have nothing to do with `def` itself. Your examples are just simple methods that return Hash/Array. First example is equivalent to:

```
def test 
  return { t: a , h: b }
end
```

In Ruby it is legal to omit `return`, value of last expression is returned than, in this example a Hash.

To write function similar to your example, just write

```
def test(a, b)
  @t = a
  @h = b
end
```

no braces/brackets needed.

Answer (score 0):

> I am confuse about the def syntax. I know it is function

No, `def` defines a method, not a function. There are no functions in Ruby.

> but when to use {} and when to use []. Not sure what it called so I cannot search the internet.

`{}` is a `Hash` literal. In other languages, this might be called a *map*, a *dictionary*, or (in PHP) an *associative array*.

`[]` is an `Array` literal. In other languages, this might also be called a *vector* or (in Python) a *list*. Note that it is in fact *exactly* the same in PHP, the array literal from the Ruby method `pieces` can be cut&pasted verbatim into a PHP function, and it will just work, because the two syntaxes are identical.

When to use which depends on what you want to do with it. An array allows you to retrieve elements by a numeric index, a hash allows you to retrieve elements by an arbitrary key.

> I have php knowledge and not familiar with this type of syntax. For the first one, in php I would write like
>
> ```
> function test ($a,$b)
> {
> $t=$a,
> $h=$b
> }
> ```

No, that's in no way equivalent to the Ruby version. For starters, the PHP function has 2 parameters, the Ruby method has 0. This would be equivalent to a Ruby method like this:

```
def test(a, b)
  @t, @h = a, b
end
```

I don't know PHP, so take this with a grain of salt, but I believe, these are equivalent PHP functions:

```php
function test() { return [ 't' => this->a, 'h' => this->b ]; }
// since `a` and `b` in the Ruby method aren't variables, they can only be methods

function pieces() { 
    return [ 'the horse and the hound and the horn that belonged to',
             'the farmer sowing his corn that kept' ];
};
```

As you can see, the array literal syntax in Ruby is actually the *exact same* syntax as in PHP.